# How does "strict" mode in javascript change the output of this code?

Tags: javascript, output, arrow-functions, strict

```
console.log((function(x, f = () => x) {
var x;
var y = x;
x = 2;
return [x, y, f()];
})(1));
```

I found this interesting puzzle a few days ago from here https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/3928607cb8fdba42e712

The answer without "strict" mode is : **[2, 1, 1]**.
Although with "strict" mode it is : **[2, 1, 2]**.

I can't figure out how the output changes with **"strict"** mode in js.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i get for both `[2, 1, 1]` ...

Comment: I was using scratch js with babel(6.7.7) transformer, I got **[2,1,2]** from there, it was using "use strict" by default, I assumed that is the problem. My bad.@NinaScholz

Comment: It's probably rather an incorrect transpilation. default parameters are evaluated in their own scopes.